# UIWebView within a UIScrollView like the Apple Mail.app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a view similar to what you see when reading an email in the Apple iOS Mail.app, where you can pinch anywhere in the view to zoom the UIWebView in and out, and the header at the top stays the same size.

Also, scrolling up/down should scroll the entire view, not just the UIWebView.
Scrolling left and right only scrolls the UIWebView left/right, it does not affect the header.

I've already tried using a UITableView with the UIWebView as a view within a cell or as a header/footer view, but I could not the scrolling and zooming do not work correctly.

I am now trying to put a UIWebView within a UIScrollView and can't seem to get the scrolling to work correctly this way either, but it seems to be a better approach than putting the UIWebView in a UITableViewCell.

Here is a simple representation of the view hierarchy I am trying to create:

```
UIScrollView
-- UIView (this is the "header" view)
-- UIWebView
```

I am not sure if I need to disable scrolling/zooming on the UIWebView, or how to handle the scroll events for the container UIScrollView or the UIWebView internal scrollview.

Thanks in advance for any examples and advice! Please let me know if I left out any details.

Comment: UIWebViews naturally have a scroll view components in it. You can access them with `self.webView.scrollView`

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the webview's scrollview. Are you suggesting to insert subviews there? That would probably mess with the internal structure of the webview, which seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already found a solution for your problem but I was facing the same and I wanted to share my solution.

I implemented a custom `UIWebView` with the same behavior as the native mail app.
Maybe it will save someone some valuable time :) I know I wish there was such a thing when I was struggling.

This is the link to the project:https://github.com/catalinaturlea/HeaderWebView

If you find any problems or think about any improvements, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know that a web view contains a scroll view then you are fine but I would suggest the following and it worked for me once:

Add a UIView between the scroll view and the other elements inside it (including the web view) and let iOS handles the rest of the stuff (gestures and scrolling events)

```
UIScrollView
-- UIView (Just a wrapper as big as the content of the scroll view)
   -- UIView (this is the "header" view)
   -- UIWebView
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try and report back. Would you by any chance be able to share the code that worked for you?

Comment: I meant the concept works for me, I simply add a UIView which as big as my scrollable content needs and add it to the scroll view, then add my content to it

Comment: How would this allow zooming and panning of the webview, while allowing the header view to remain the same size and at the same position within the scroll view?